# Unable to load the file system codec

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, pyinstaller

Here is the code i try to compile into .exe

```
from tkinter import * 

fenetre = Tk()

label = Label(fenetre, text="Hello World")
label.pack()

fenetre.mainloop()
```

I open the cmd and type

> pyinstaller test.py

Everything goes well, "22826 INFO: Building COLLECT out00-COLLECT.toc completed successfully."

But when i launch my application i got this error message :

> Fatal Python error : initfsencoding: unable to load the file system
>   codec zipimport.ZipImportError: can't find module 'encodings'
>
> Current thread 0x00001954 (most recent call first):

I searched everywhere for like 2 hours nothing work...

I tried cx_Freezer too

Do you have any idea how to fix it ?

Thanks !

Comment: Try with a different version of python and check which versions are supported by pyinstaller.

Comment: it's still the same

Answer (score 0):

I used to have same problem using

> pyinstaller --onefile my_file.py

I was using Python 3.7, After switching to 3.6 it works just fine!
So its probably that 3.7 isn't supported yet by PyInstaller